# LiveCharts UWP : Add Margin space between Axislabel and Title

Tags: uwp, livecharts

Is there any way to add Margin space in Red line ?
I want to Add Margin space between Axislabel and Title.

LiveCharts : https://lvcharts.net/

[image]

Comment: I have never used this library but in case you don't know the full access of the properties you can set, here's the link :
https://lvcharts.net/App/documentation/beta/wpf/LiveCharts-AxisCore

Have you tried tweaking the Separator property?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that it's possible to do it by setting a property. But as a dirty hack, you could define a `LabelFormatter` for your axis labels, and add space / margin before the actual labels.